# How to dynamically select a range of cells in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to select the range of cells which starts after **Test_start** and ends before **Test_stop**.In the sample shown the range to select would be A4:A6,
I have manually selected the range and found the total to be 6 as it should be.

The data will remain in the same column and will always begin with **Test_start** and end with **Test_stop**, however it may begin at any row .

If it helps I have only one data set per sheet.

I wish to achieve this using Excel formulas and not vba !!.

[image: Sample excel column]

Comment: If `test_xxx` is a named range, just press `ctrl+G` and type `test_start:test_stop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=MATCH("test_stop";A:A;0)-MATCH("test_start";A:A;0)+1

You can manipulate the result by adding integers to the result / subtracting them as well.

The formula works properly only for one column.

Cheers.

Comment: I do not follow,
are you suggesting that i do something like this 


= SUM((MATCH("START",A:A,0)+1):(MATCH("START",A:A,0)-1))


this does not work !!

Comment: You were on the right path :)

=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("test_start";A:A;0)+1;1;4)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH("test_stop";A:A;0)-1;1;4)))

Just adapt the starting and end point. 
And once again: Works only in one column.

Comment: @Pascal Using `INDIRECT` is not recommended because it is volatile. `INDEX` should always be preferred. See my answer for alternative with `INDEX`. Also, your edits to your formula should be reflected in your original answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Thank you for that information. Didn't know that. `INDIRECT`. worked for me every time I used it. Though your answer is more lean and straight forward!

Comment: @Pascal Using `INDIRECT` is sometimes unavoidable but usually `INDEX` can be used instead. `INDIRECT` doesn't really cause an issue for small spreadsheets, but for very large spreadsheets, volatile functions such as `INDIRECT` will drastically slow down calculation times. This is why they typically should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Am I the only one that thought that `selection` in the sentence `I want to select the range of cells` means selection? :D

Comment: There is some syntax error with your syntax and im too lazy to debug it :P, However I went over the documentation for the respective functions and recreated your solution ,
=SUM(INDIRECT((ADDRESS(MATCH("START",A:A,0)+1,1))&":"&(ADDRESS(MATCH("STOP",A:A,0)-1,1))))           
This works ........
The optional fields for the ADDRESS method were not doing much for me so i omitted them .

Answer (score 0):

No.

Selecting a range in Excel is an action. Formulas return result. You cannot make an action through a formula.

Comment: ok , does excel provide any inbuilt tool to perform this type of task.

Comment: @EdmundCarvalho - vba

Comment: @Vityata FYI, this is possible. See my answer.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - you need to select it. Your answer simply gives a calculation. But the selected cell does not move.

Comment: @Vityata I guess technically yes the "selected" cells are the entire `A` column, but the use of `INDEX` effectively changes the sum range dynamically based on the start and end points.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - idk, the OK says `manually selected the range` and etc. For me this is selection as an action and not a variable in a formula argument.

Comment: @Vityata "manually selected the range" was just referring to that is what he/she currently must do because he/she couldn't figure out a way for a formula to automatically select the range. Anyway, we could argue semantics, but I'm not sure what is the point because the formula with `INDEX` returns the desired result. The details of "how" are irrelevant as long as it isn't more inefficient than it needs to be.

Comment: @Vityata I think I have created some confusion , 
I simply want the range of  cells between the start and stop cell eg (A4:A6) so that I can perform operations like sum on it , im curious to know how this can be achieved using vba

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

Use this formula:

```
= SUM(INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Test_start",A:A)+1):INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Test_stop",A:A)-1))
```

See below for working example.

[image]

Comment: I tried the exact same formula which you provided and it returns the last value in the data set rather than the sum, I will recreate your method some other time :)  .

Comment: @EdmundCarvalho Not sure what to tell you. This is why I posted a screen capture to demonstrate that it works.